# Get a column without adding it to the group by

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select year, gender, max(nHospitalizations) from (select TO_CHAR(i.since, 'YYYY') as year, u.gender, h.name,count(h.name) as nHospitalizations from hospital h 
join hospitalization i on i.hospital = h.name
join person u on i.person = u.numberID
group by TO_CHAR(i.since, 'YYYY'), u.gender, h.name)
group by year, gender
order by year desc, gender asc
;
```

I have this query, and it's pretty much doing what I want it too, except, I want to know the hospital name with the most hospitalizations per year, but when I add the h.name to the select, SQL makes me add it to the outer group by, which would mean I would be getting the count per year, gender and hospital name like in the subquery, instead of the hospital with most hospitalizations per year and gender, how can I add the h.name to the outer query without adding it to the outer group by?

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

You want to use window functions for this:

```
select *
from (select count(*) as nHospitalizations, to_char(i.since, 'YYYY') as year,
             u.gender, h.name,
             row_number() over (partition by min(i.since) order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from hospital h join
           hospitalization i
           i.hospital = h.name join
           person u
           on i.person = u.numberID
      group by TO_CHAR(i.since, 'YYYY'), u.gender, h.name
     ) x
where serqnum = 1
```